# Dividing by $x!$

Tags: combinatorics

I have 2 questions

1. We want to divide 20 people into 4 teams such that each team has 5 people. I did this:

$$\begin{equation} \frac{\begin{pmatrix}20\\5\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}15\\5\end{pmatrix} \times\begin{pmatrix}10\\5\end{pmatrix} \times\begin{pmatrix}5\\5\end{pmatrix}}{4!}\end{equation}$$

2. when I want to put on 1 line 4 flags from country "x", 3 flags from country "y" , and 5 flags from country "z" we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix}12\\4\end{pmatrix} \times\begin{pmatrix}8\\3\end{pmatrix} \times\begin{pmatrix}5\\3\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}$$

*why don't we divide by $3!$ in (2)?

*why do  we divide by $4!$ in (1)?

Please help me understand!

Comment: i sorry about the slepping
i use on another site with same affect...
i will thanks you if you can help me

Comment: 1. The order of the teams **IS NOT** important. 2. The order of the flags **IS** important.

Comment: @barakmanos
i will thanks you if you can explain me that well
why the order of flag is important?
and why the order of team NOT important?
what

Comment: This is the most logical interpretation. $4$ teams are just $4$ teams. It doesn't make sense that their order is important. In the case of ordering flags on a line, however, it makes sense that the order is important.

Comment: In your second question, you do not have identical flags for all countries.

Comment: @barakmanos
if on (2) i will dividing by 3! what will happend?
thanks!

Comment: You will get $\frac16$ of the original result.

Comment: @barakmanos. yeh , sure
but if the order wasn't important on (2) how can i do it?(with nCr?)

Comment: If the order of the flags was not important then there would be only $1$ way to arrange them on the line!!!

Comment: @barakmanos
so how you cnculate with nCr ? if the order not important (1 way to order that)
and why only 1 way?
the first flag has 12 places

Comment: $\binom{4+3+5}{4+3+5}=1$. BTW, I've just noticed that the answer for question #2 is wrong! The answer is $\binom{4+3+5}{4}\times\binom{3+5}{3}\times\binom{5}{5}$, and you can also write it as $\frac{(4+3+5)!}{4!\times3!\times5!}$.

Comment: You meant the number of ways of arranging the flags is $$\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{\color{red}{5}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Q1:

Since no indication has been given that the teams are **labelled**, i.e. distinguishable, e.g. Leopards, Panthers, Lions, Tigers, we treat them as **unlabelled**.

Clearly ABCDE | FGHIJ | ... for instance is the same as FGHIJ | ABCDE | ...

and as there are $4$ unlabelled teams, we divide by $4!$

Btw, although the expression uses combinations, you can see that it is taking all permutations of $20$ divided into $4$ groups, removing permutations within each group, and also between groups, i.e. $\dfrac{20!}{5!5!5!5!4!}$

Q2

Here, obviously the flags of each country are distinguishable, so although combinations have been used, it is identical to a permutation approach, $\dfrac{12!}{4!3!5!}$